# Can't connect to Postgres 14 from inside container

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

In our development environment, we run Postgres in containers in a Kubernetes cluster.

To access the database, service container can just use the cluster-internal host name for the Postgres service.

Recently, we have upgraded from Postgres 11 to 14 and we can no longer connect port 5432 through the cluster-internal host name (Neither `psql` nor `telnet` works). The error message for telnet is: `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

When I use `kubectl port-forward` and access the same service from my laptop, I can connect to the database using `psql`.
Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the FQDN of Postgres service as the "cluster-internal host name" i.e `<postgres-svc-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` to access it ?

Comment: @SaifeddineRajhi It turns out it's because the default `listen_addresses` is `localhost` and our old configuration file with this set to the right value is still in the `.../postgres/11/...` directory.